# Is there an Online Programming Bible?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, wiki

I'm interested in Programming especially in `Java`. Is there a page, which explains different informatics topics in Java or generic for all OOP languages? I mean something wikipedia-styled, but more understandable and just for programming/informatics.

Maybe with exercises, but basicly it should explain different problems of informatics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of good online resources for learning Java, and many of them will teach you good OOP practices as well.

- [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)
- [Java API Specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)
- [Thinking in Java 4th ed.](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4) by Bruce Eckel
- [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html)
- [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html)

For programming in general though, I recommend [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

Comment: This this way you need to read!!

Comment: A good way to access the Java Tutorials as reference material is via The Really Big Index (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html).

Answer (score 4):

For programming topics **on Java**, go to the Oracle (Sun) Java site. That's the holy grails of everything regarding Java. For a Wikipedia-style format, just go to wikibooks (as it will have topics on Java and other programming languages, not just OO.)

Other than that, a short answer to your question will be simply **NO**. Programming is too complex a topic for someone to create the type of material that you are asking.

If you are seriously interested in programming (and I mean seriously), focus on one language alone and learn it (as opposed to looking for the perfect language or trying to analyze all possible alternatives and falling into "paralysis by analysis".)

Again, if you are serious...

### just pick one of the following:

1. C
2. Python
3. Ruby
4. Scala

C would make you face the nitty gritty of computing and people have been successful in learning programming with C as its programming languages (don't let OO and/or Ruby/Python/Java/.NET fanboys tell you otherwise.)

Python and Ruby are extremely beautiful languages that will teach to program, and do not force you to make everything into an object (a really retarded idea, more on that below.) Scala is another elegant and effective alternative.

### Learn The Fundamentals of Programming First, the OO Analysis and Modeling (not the other way around

Avoid languages that force you to write everything in objects. That includes Java and C#. I've been working with Java for 12 years now, and it is a reliable platform. But it is a retarded language in that it does not allow you for procedural programming. Not everything is an object nor should be modeled as an object, sometimes not even in complex systems. People are still grappling with how to program correctly using a OO paradigm and they keep failing because they still don't get the capabilities and limitations of OO modeling and analysis.

So my suggestion is not to learn programming with Java (or C#). Go with the hard procedural (C) or the elegant, paradigm-agnostic (Python, Ruby or Scala.) Focus on modularity, structured programming and algorithms. Then, later you will be better equipped to truly understand where OO languages fit in.

---

I'm not going to delve into why I chose these 4 options or why I advise against Java and C#. That debate has been discussed a plenty and you can find it easily in stackoverflow and/or google. That's just my suggestion, from my experience (Java and otherwise), a suggestion that I always give to those serious about learning programming.

In the end, it doesn't really matter which of those four you pick. Just flip a coin, pick one and stick to it until you are decent with it. Focus on learning proper programming techniques, problem decomposition and algorithms rather than on the language itself.

Good luck.

---

**edit:**

I forgot to mention, if you are serious about learning programming, buy books. You won't learn from visiting sites. And you have to put your time in it (we are talking 4hrs a day at least... I don't see anyone learning programming with anything less than that.) Anything less is just make-believe going through the motions of learning.

Comment: sorry, i meant informatics, not programming, english is a difficult language :)

Comment: Ahhh, I see (and yes, English is a difficult language - I'm a non-native speaker two, btw). The problem with the field is that what we call Computer Science and MIS here might be called "Informatics" or "Information Sciences", and there are many fields that are related, that overlap and that might be called the same. Programming is one of the many fields among those in "Informatics". You need to find out what within "Informatics" you want to learn... *and it is very difficult to work in "Informatics" without knowing programming of one type or another.* Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.programmingpraxis.com could help you a lot since i go through most of the examples from there.Have a look.

**EDIT:**
http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/392/javaprograms/
http://projecteuler.net

Comment: The page seems to have design errors with FF 3.6 but seems to be good

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend imo the best book written about Java.

[Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) by Joshua Bloch

Comment: He is interested in web sites..

Comment: Indeed, the OP wants websites, a misguided (and cheap idea) IMO. +1 for kajo for mentioning Bloch's classic though. Unfortunately, it requires a level of maturity to really get value from it. I doubt it can be used for learning how to program (as opposed to how to program **better**).

Comment: oh, sry, i didn't notice. Some sample chapters are here http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0201310058 and I think that this book is must read for all Java programmers. He could borrow it or buy :)

Comment: +1 I have to agree with you it is a must read book!

Answer (score 1):

Continuing the Bill's recommendation

> 1. http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm.html
> 2. Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend these: [Sun Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/),
[FreewareJava.com](http://www.freewarejava.com/),
[java2s](http://www.java2s.com/)